# Android Customer Login

Tags: android, facebook

This is my simple user login asynk task and I have stored the response params in shared preferences,

```
class logintask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       pdilog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
       pdilog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
       pdilog.show();
       super.onPreExecute();
       }


   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       JSONObject jsonObject;
       try {
           response = LoginPostHit.getJSONfromURL(params[0], params[1]);
           JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
           customerid = _jobject.getString("CustomerID");
           serverresponse = _jobject.getString("Result");
           emailaddress=_jobject.getString("EmailAddress");
           customername = _jobject.getString("CustomerName");
           mobilenumber = _jobject.getString("MobileNumber");
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return response;
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       pdilog.dismiss();
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       if (serverresponse.equals("Success")) {
           Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.VERIFICATION, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
           editor.putString(AppConstants.LOGGEDIN, "1");
           editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMERID, customerid);
           editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMERNAME, customername);
           editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMERMOBILENUMBER, mobilenumber);
           editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMEREMAIL,emailaddress);
           editor.commit();
           i.putExtra("CustomerName",customername);
           startActivity(i);
           } else {
               final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LoginActivity.this);
               dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
               dialog.setContentView(R.layout.wrongusrnamepass);
               //dialog.setTitle("Wrong Credentials");
               TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
               text.setText("Incorrect Email/Password Combination");

               dialog.show();
               Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
               declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });
               }
          }
      }
```

and this is my Facebook login method, from here also I have stored the values in the same shared preferences

```
lginbtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.tvfacebook);


lginbtn.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email");
//LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
lginbtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        Log.d("Accesstoken", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
        RequestData(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
        //i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        //startActivity(i);
        }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancel() {
       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login attempt Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onError(FacebookException error) {
   //infomation.setText("Login attempt failed.");

   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login attempt failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void RequestData(AccessToken accesstoken) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accesstoken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                String firstname = "";
                String lastname = "";
                json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if (json != null) {
                        JSONObject jsonPhoto = null;
                        JSONObject jsonPhotoo = null;
                        Session session = null;
//                      String text = "<b>FirstName :</b> " + json.getString("first_name") + "<b>LastName :</b> " + json.getString("last_name") + "<br><br><b>Email :</b> " + json.getString("email") + "<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> " + json.getString("link");
                        email = json.getString("email");
                        name = json.getString("name");
                        first_name = json.optString("first_name");
                        last_name = json.optString("last_name");
                        picture = json.getString("picture");

                        JSONObject jsonPhoto1 = json.getJSONObject("picture");
                        if (jsonPhoto1.has("data")) {
                            jsonPhoto = jsonPhoto1.getJSONObject("data");
                            url = jsonPhoto.getString("url");
                        }

                        new fblogintask().execute(url);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    class fblogintask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>

    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (serverresponse.equals("Success")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.VERIFICATION, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString(AppConstants.LOGGEDIN, "1");
                editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMERID, customerid);
                editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMERNAME, customername);
                editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMERMOBILENUMBER, mobilenumber);
                editor.putString(AppConstants.CUSTOMEREMAIL,emailaddress);
                startActivity(i);
            } else
            {
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                response = FbLoginPostHit.getJSONfromURL(first_name, last_name, email, voids[0]);
                JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                customerid = _jobject.getString("CustomerID");
                serverresponse = _jobject.getString("Result");
                emailaddress=_jobject.getString("EmailAddress");
                customername = _jobject.getString("CustomerName");
                mobilenumber = _jobject.getString("MobileNumber");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Now the problem is that in first case when I am getting value from the shared 
pref in second activity then it is passing the values but when I am getting values from the shred prefs in the second case it is giving null..I want is whether user logins with fb or simple login. I get the required params in next activity,,Someone suggest me how to do so

Comment: this is how i m getting values in anoher activity    customername = prefs.getString(AppConstants.CUSTOMERNAME, "");

Comment: Did you verify response has keys and values.Like response has "CustomerID" tag or not

Comment: yes it has customer id ,name,etc all of the values

Comment: Check my below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your FbLoginTask you forgot to commit your shared preference updates. 
According to Docs, values in shared preference will not save until you call apply or commit on your shared preference.

In postExecute of your AsyncTask commit your preference values before starting Activity.

Comment: One small suggestion, start your class name with capital letter